# Returning unexpected negative values

Tags: c, recursion, combinations

This is a simple recursive code to calculate the number of ways a chef can prepare a dish, if she has 'n' sets of food, 'm' days to serve and if she doesn't wish to repeat a food for 'k' days.

```
int ncomb(int n, int m, int k)
{
    if (k > n)  //1
        return 0;

    if (m == 1) //2
        return n;

    if (k == 0) //3
        return n * (ncomb(n, m-1, k) % 1000000007);

    else //4
        return n * (ncomb(n-1, m-1, k-1) % 1000000007);
}
```

The return values in the code is either n or 0 and n can never go below because of the conditions 1 and 3, but still if for some inputs (eg: [n - 433, m - 43, k - 3]) the output is negative, can someone give an idea why this happens and what's wrong in this code?

Comment: The reason is simple: after multiplication the result is going beyond integer range. Try using `long long`

Comment: Maybe even `long long unsigned`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value of an int (signed int32) is 0x7FFFFFFF which is exactly 2147483647.

After mulitplication (`return n * (ncomb(n, m-1, k) % 1000000007);`) you overflow this value.

Try "long" (max 9223372036854775807) instead:

```
    long ncomb(long n, long m, long k)
    {
        if (k > n)  //1
            return 0;

        if (m == 1) //2
            return n;

        if (k == 0) //3
            return n * (ncomb(n, m-1, k) % 1000000007);

        else //4
            return n * (ncomb(n-1, m-1, k-1) % 1000000007);
    }
```